# Can I import playlists from Itunes to GrooveShark?

Tags: import, grooveshark

Is there a way to import playlists from iTunes into GrooveShark rather than manually adding all of the music I like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [GroovyLists.](http://groovylists.com/)

> Groovylists take your playlist (only exported iTunes XML Playlists at the moment) and add them to Grooveshark.